# How to convert cell text to comment for entire column?

Tags: excel, vba, comments

This does it individually but I need each cell in the column to convert to a comment.

```
Sub CelltoComment()

Range("B2").Value = ""
    Range("b2").AddComment
    Range("b2").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("b2").Comment.Text Text:=Range("c2").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Then loop through the desired range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CelltoComment()

    Dim myCell  As Range

    For Each myCell In Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)

        With myCell
            .Value = ""
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text myCell.Offset(0, 1).Text
        End With
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Most of the trick is done by Offset(0,1), which takes the next column and `Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)`, which takes the cells with values only. If you have cells with formula, they will be avoided.